# Where can I read the Console output in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

Installed the new Visual Studio Community for Mac. Just tried to run some existing command line app. Where does Console.WriteLine output on VisualStudio for Mac? Is that possible to redirect on the Terminal?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

View menu > Pads > Application Output

Comment: Has this been changed, I don't see that option?

Comment: @kbpontius It may be labelled "Application Output - <ProjectName>" where `<ProjectName>` is the name of the running project.

Answer (score 1):

When I press the play button on the top left it launches "Terminal" and runs the code in there. Try starting a new console app and see if that works with the given hello world.

Comment: Thanks, it works with a new project build on Mac, but not with my project build on PC VS 2015 Enterprise edition ;-(

Answer (score -1):

Slightly different but same sort of topic, so thought I'd add information here for anyone else looking.

On VS for Mac (version 8.7.8), I see "Build Output" on the "Errors" dialog (View -> Pads -> Errors). Took me ages to find, hope that helps someone!

[image: Errors - Build Output]