# System.Net.WebException: 'Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)'

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin

I have this page below ,I want send data with json to my PHP page to insert users to MySQL database.
but the connection failed :"System.Net.WebException: 'Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)'"
My page in xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="fullApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Margin="0,30,0,0" Padding="20">
        <Entry x:Name="user" Placeholder="UserName"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="pass" Placeholder="Password" ></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="phone" Placeholder="Phone Number"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="gover" Placeholder="Governorate"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="city" Placeholder="City"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="street" Placeholder="Street"></Entry>
        <Button x:Name="rigister" Clicked="Rigister_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

My page on cs :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace fullApp
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pass.IsPassword = true;
        }

        void Rigister_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            PostJson("http://localhost:3308/test/API/rigister_user.php", new users
            {
                username = user.Text,
                password = pass.Text,
                PhoneNumber = phone.Text,
                Governorate = gover.Text,
                City = city.Text,
                Street = street.Text
            });
            void PostJson(string uri, users postParameters)
            {
                string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postParameters);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
                }
                var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", httpWebResponse.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

            }
        }

    }
        public class users
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string Governorate { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Street { get; set; }
        }
}
```

the debuging stop on this line whis i get error message :"System.Net.WebException: 'Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)'":

```
using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
```

Login page

[image]

Registration Page

[image]

After sign in or registering

[image]

Comment: use the IP or FQDN instead of localhost.   Verify that your web server can accept remote connections.  Test connectivity using the web browser on your device/emulator.

Comment: @Jason in localhost which ip i use? 127.0.01 or the wifi ip 192.168......?

Comment: the actual IP address of the server.  127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost

Comment: have you tried posting to your php page externally using something like PostMan? You are trying to eliminate if the issue lies with your C# code or if its the PHP file

Comment: i tested postman and registered successfully

Comment: @Jason it is worked Correctly in website :)

Comment: Can you share the rest of the application output? And have you tried to play around in the Android project settings with the client handler and TLS/SSL options?

Comment: @Saamer where do you want me to share it brother?

Comment: Either in a pastebin or just in the question

Comment: @Saamer I added it to main question if i understand what you want :)

Comment: Here's how to get the application output https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795547/11104068 and here's how to change the SSL & Client handler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows

Comment: @Saamer the output is very long

Comment: Yes that's why you can use a pastebin for it

Comment: @Saamer https://pastebin.com/xYQVBD08

Comment: I couldn't find the System.Net.WebException or the error anywhere in the application output. Could you please share the output where the exception is taking place. Also did you try to change you SSL & Client Handler settings?

Comment: it fixed when i tested it on website

Comment: @Saamer same problem again with local host : https://pastebin.com/8M12nNFK

Comment: @sermed is the wifi on in your device. Go to reddit.com and see if the page loads. Also try to use your IP address (eg: 10.0.2.2) instead of localhost

Comment: @Saamer i used my IP but also same thing

Comment: Do you want to share a Github project with a reproducible sample, so I can take a look at it there and fix it

Comment: @Saamer in case of http and success the request on rigister_user.php page ,i want to get success message response ,how can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient and make it an asynchronous function:

```
async Task<string> PostJson(string uri, users postParameters)
{
  string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postParameters);
  using (var client = new HttpClient());
  var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(postData));
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
  {
     string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
     throw new ApplicationException(message);
  }
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Update:

I know this doesn't solve to OPs question but it's just a much more elegant way to do it.